# Unable to access wordpress page after update

Tags: wordpress

I'm facing an error with wordpress. I updated  wordpress page by mistake and I'm getting error

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.

When I try to access the page by admin. I can't revert the change since the unable to access the page from admin. Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you checked your email inbox for instructions. ?

Comment: yes but unfortunately it's empty :(

Comment: what was the last thing you remember you did ? before this site crash?

Comment: Added  a <p> tag inside home and it got auto saved.

Comment: Look in your php error log

Comment: That's great then just go to your CPanel and navigate to that file...  remove that tag from that... See if that works

Comment: @AgentP What makes you think there's CPanel?

Comment: @Johannes Basically what I thought was each website will have some kind of file manager .. am I wrong.?

Comment: I had to access the wp_post table and had to change content of the particular post. Thanks everyone :). And really sorry about low details I was in a quite hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly clarify your question, you updated one of the pages in your WordPress site or did you update WordPress to the latest version and got an error afterwards when trying to log in within the admin dashboard?

If it is a page you can't access, try disabling your plugins and see if it will be accessible. You can also try to enable WP_Debug to true from within the wp-config.php within your back-end file manager and see if the exact issue will be displayed so as to assist you with further troubleshooting.

Alternatively, if the issue arising is due to a WordPress update to the latest version, you can try renaming the plugins folder temporary from within your backend as a form of troubleshooting, if that fails, temporary rename your theme (/wp-content/themes/theme_name) to try and pinpoint the exact issue. All this can be done with the WordPress folder from cPanel, file manager.

If the above fails, go a step further and try doing stuff like PHP memory increase, post_max_size &c.

If all the above fails, refer to WordPress documentation on how to do a manual WordPress update and hopefully, the issue will be fixed.

Note: The above is just an insight of what you can look into and not a step by step guide to fixing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation :)